# Declension of "хорошая мать"

Tags: грамматика

I need some help with this. Can you pls take a closer look if I did this ok?

Np хорóшие мáтери

Gp хорóших матерéй

Dp хорóшим матеря'м

Ap хорóших матерéй

Ip хорóшими матеря'ми

Lp хорóших матеря'х

Accusative animate

Ns хóрошая мáть

Gs хорóшей мáтери

Ds хорóшей мáтери

As хорóшую мáть

Is хорошей матерью

Ls хорóшей мáтери

Accusative animate

Comment: Yes, you did this ok.

Comment: What about this one?

Comment: Instrumental sing. is хорошей матерью. Everything else is OK. But what's the question? You should better look into the Russian wiki.

Comment: I looked but the internet reference i used was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have the mistake here: Ns хóрошая мáть 
The right way is: Ns хoро'шая мáть 
And there will be like: Is хоро'шей ма`терью

Answer (score -1):

Well, it sure does look correct... Actually, i use "О" to help myself in L.P. I.e: О хороших матерях. Good luck with your studies (Glad someone remembers us funky Russians...)!